# Date field uploaded via dataloader seems to get one day out when uploading

Tags: data-loader

We uploaded some data into Salesforce but it turns out that the date imported into salesforce got one day out. For example, if we imported 04/06/2017 it turns out to be 03/06/2017 in the Salesforce system.

Is it a known issue in Salesforce?

Comment: May be a timezone issue.

Comment: @TusharSharma it is a date field not a datetime field and both the upload user and the end user are in uk time zone.

Comment: Make sure in dataloader, timzeone is synced with salesforce user: http://www.simplysfdc.com/2013/09/salesforce-data-loader-time-zone.html